# Customizing page transitions with Convertigo

Tags: ionic-framework, convertigo

I am currently building a cross-platform mobile application with Convertigo Studio, and the iOS default transition between pages does not fit well with the design : I would like the transitions between pages in the iOS app to be identical to the Android ones.

I have narrowed the problem to the Ionic `navCtrl.push()` call, probably made by the Convertigo `PushPage` component.

According to [this blog post](http://entwicklertagebuch.com/blog/2018/02/how-to-implement-custom-page-transitions-in-an-ionic-app/), it is possible to force transitions with the `animation` field of the call configuration object :

```
this.navCtrl.push(MyPageComponent, null, {animate: true, animation: "transition-android"});
```

Convertigo Studio allows me to edit the `animate` and `duration` fields, but not `animation`.

Without patching the Studio, is there a way to override the iOS default page transition ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes in 7.5.7 version Convertigo studio does not expose the transition type property for push pages. This has been added in 7.6

Nevertheless, you can customize your template (The mobilebuildet_tpl_7_5_7 project in the workspace) the add a default transition into the app module this way :

in ionicTpl/src/app/app.module.ts

Change line

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, deepLinkConfig)
```

to

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
  pageTransition: 'ios-transition'
}, deepLinkConfig)
```

This way, all page transitions can be set to iOS or Android mode whatever the app runs on.

Do not forget to reload your project (Right click on project->Reload your project) to have the MobileBuilder to regenerate the Ionic project sources and re-execute the app viewer to rebuild the app.

Hope That Helps !

Comment: Hello,
I tried it and it doesn't seem to have any effect.
I guess I'll port my app to 7.6.